# How to echo define value in PHP?

Tags: php, echo

My code is here:

```
<?php define("SITENAME","Page TITLE");?>
```

I want to echo define value like:

```
<?php echo "<?=SITENAME?>";?>
```

Would someone tell me how?

Comment: <?php
define("SITENAME","Page TITLE");
echo constant("SITENAME");
?>

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php   . example given here will clarify all your doubt

Comment: i have this type

echo "SITENAME  : Another Title Text.";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php 
    define("SITENAME","Page TITLE");    
    echo "My website title: ".SITENAME; 
?>
```

output : `My website title: Page TITLE`

Comment: You don't need `constant()` if you just want to echo/use the value, see @GeoTom's answer. The `constant()` function is helpful if you want to read a constant using a string variable.

Comment: @halfer . I updated my answer. Used for clarity but you right.

Answer (score 5):

You can echo the value of constant as below

```
define("SITENAME","Page TITLE");
echo SITENAME.': My New Content Here';
```

This gives : `Page TITLE: My New Content Here`

For more reference:

```
define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
echo CONSTANT; // outputs "Hello world."
echo Constant; // outputs "Constant" and issues a notice.

define("GREETING", "Hello you.", true);
echo GREETING; // outputs "Hello you."
echo Greeting; // outputs "Hello you."

// Works as of PHP 7
define('ANIMALS', array(
    'dog',
    'cat',
    'bird'
));
echo ANIMALS[1]; // outputs "cat"
```

Comment: how to add some text with echo

Comment: i.e.  This gives : Page TITLE : SOME ANOTHER TEXT FOR THIS